# Merge html classes with defaults in Ruby helper

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper, parameters

I am trying to write a Ruby helper for outputting SVG sprites.

Classes that are passed in through `options` (`class: "some-class"`) don't appear to be merged and output.

```
def ui_svg(icon_classes, size = false, options = {})

  options = {
    class: icon_classes,
    "aria-hidden" => true,
    role: "presentation",
    width: (size ? size : nil),
    height: (size ? size : nil)
  }

  content_tag(:svg, options.merge( options ) ) do
    content_tag(:use, nil, "xlink:href" => "#" + icon_classes)
  end

end
```

If I just call `= ui_svg "icon-envelope", 16` the I get the correct output:

```
<svg class="icon-envelope" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" width="16" height="16">
  <use xlink:href="#icon-envelope"></use>
</svg>
```

However when I call it with `= ui_svg "icon-envelope", 16, class: "some-class"`,  `icon-envelope` is never output to the first `content_tag`; only `some-class`.

```
<svg class="some-class" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" width="16" height="16">
  <use xlink:href="#icon-envelope"></use>
</svg>
```

**How can I ensure both the `icon_classes` and classes passed in through `options` are output on the outermost `content_tag`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two different variables with the same name `options`, one from the method arguments list and the other defined within the method body. The latter hides the former. Rename one of those variables.

```
def ui_svg(icon_classes, size = false, options = {})
  svg_tag_options = options.merge(
    :class => [icon_classes, options[:class]].reject(&:blank?).join(" "),
    "aria-hidden" => true,
    :role => "presentation",
    :width => (size ? size : nil),
    :height => (size ? size : nil)
  )

  content_tag(:svg, svg_tag_options) do
    content_tag(:use, nil, "xlink:href" => "#" + icon_classes)
  end 
end
```

#### UPDATE

The code has been updated in response to the edited question.

Comment: I have tried this previously. If I use the following `= ui_svg "icon-envelope", 16, class: "icon-large"` the class applied to the outermost `content_tag` is `icon-large` and does not include `icon-envelope`.

Comment: Your edit to the OP clarifies things. I have updated my answer

Comment: Missing a comma after `.join()` but yes, this is exactly what I was looking for.